# Como trocar uma imagem pelo Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html

Preciso mudar uma imagem pelo javaScript mas não estou conseguindo, tentei da seguinte forma e não funcionou;

html

```
<img id="imagemPerfil" src="img/user1.png" alt="profile image"  class="circle z-depth-2 responsive-img activator gradient-45deg-light-blue-cyan gradient-shadow">
```

JavaScript

```
document.getElementById("imagemPerfil").src ="<?php echo'../img/perfilUsuario/'.$usuario_pesquisado->getImg(); ?>";
```

notei que o valor é recebido pelo php, porém ele não é passado ao src da imagem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No head da página onde estará o javascript**

```
<script src="local/do//jQuery.js"></script>
```

**No contexto do HTML / Quem mostra a imagem**

```
<img id="imagemPerfil"
     alt="profile image"
     class="circle z-depth-2 responsive-img activator gradient-45deg-light-blue-cyan gradient-shadow">
```

**No contexto do Javascript / Quem pede a imagem**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var params = {
            Request: "GetImgPerf"
        };
        $.get("PerfilUsuarioController.php", params, function (respImg) {
            $("#imagemPerfil").attr("src", respImg);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Na parte onde entra o PerfilUsuarioController.php, é onde fiz o teste aqui em casa, mas para funcionar para você, Verifique no seu projeto, qual é o caminho para acessoar a imagem.

**Exemplo genérico PHP / Quem fornece a imagem**

```
class PerfilUsuarioController {

    public function verificarRequest() {
        $request = $_GET["Request"];
        switch ($request) {
            case "GetImgPerf":
                $this->getImgPerfil();
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    public function getImgPerfil() {
        // Codigo de busca do usua ou qualquer outra verificação
        print $usuario_pesquisado->getImg();
    }

}

$perf = new PerfilUsuarioController();
$perf->verificarRequest();
```

Answer (score 0):

Ola,

Eu vejo duas opcoes que voce pode utilizar, talvez com mais detalhes de como vc quer utilizar eu tenha outras ideias, mas vamos la:

voce pode atribuir a img direto no src:

```
<img id="imagemPerfil" src="<?php echo'../img/perfilUsuario/'.$usuario_pesquisado->getImg(); ?>" alt="profile image"  class="circle z-depth-2 responsive-img activator gradient-45deg-light-blue-cyan gradient-shadow">
```

Ou você cria uma requisição Ajax via javascript e no OnSucess vc troca a imagem.

Answer (score 0):

Isso talvez seja cache do navegador, ou do servidor principalmente se você estiver utilizando um CDN.

Experimente colocar uma url com parâmetros para ver se não resolve.
Exemplo: /image/arquivo.jpg**?v=2**

Comment: pior que não, eu vi pelo console que o caminho ainda é o da imagem antiga

Comment: Quando você obtém a imagem pelo url direto no Browser ela é carregada corretamente?

Comment: Experimente colocar um outro valor, e verifique pelo inspect do browser na página se esse novo valor é atribuido.

Comment: sim consigo pegar a imagem pelo browser

Comment: alterei o valor no javascript não funcionou, mesmo retirando aparte do php